# Default View in document library not appearing

Tags: powershell, document-library, view

I have created a view using Powershell for several document libraries.  The view is created and set as default for each library, yet when I visit the page, the standard view (All Documents) always appears.  I've checked the settings on the view and it is indeed the default.  Any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> when I visit the page

What page, and how do you visit it? A view is a new ASPX page so maybe you need to update some navigation items or links in HTML content. Try navigating to the library URL without the /Forms/Allitems.aspx and see which view loads first.

e.g. https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing/Brochures/

Also if you have put a view of a web part on a web part page, make sure to configure the web part to always load your Knowledge view - this has to be configured on every page, especially if you put the web part there before the view existed.